# How can I drop a constraint with multiple columns as the primary key in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

My code looks like this:

```
CONSTRAINT user_password_username_password PRIMARY KEY (username, password)
```

I need to drop this constraint because I updated the foreign keys and no longer can use password in the constraint. I also cannot simply drop the table and recreate it because it is linked to other tables. How can I drop this constraint so only username will make up the primary key?

Comment: When you say you updated the foreign keys, do you mean in this table or in other tables? When you say linked to other tables, do you mean that other tables rely on this one's primary key?

Comment: do you want to remove primary key?what constraints specifically?

Comment: Updated all the foreign keys in the database and yes, the other tables do rely on this primary key. I ended up dropping all foreign keys. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Drop all foreign key constraints referencing the `user_password_username_password` constraint.  Disable will not work; you must drop them.  You may need to drop foreign keys that reference other unique keys on the table, but I'm not sure about that.
2. Drop the `user_password_username_password` constraint on the table.
3. Create a new unique/primary key constraint on the table.
4. Create or recreate any foreign key constraints.

I believe you can do all this in a single transaction, but if it's a large table I'd consider doing this in single user mode.  You'll be dropping a primary key which causes an index rebuild for every index and constraint on the table, then potentially creating several new indexes/constraints in the foreign keys, and then creating the new primary key which again forces all the indexes and constraints on the table to rebuild.